# I can't set the selected style for individual cells in a DefaultTableModel

Tags: netbeans, java-me, lwuit

My code:

```
 Style selectedStyle = new Style();
 selectedStyle.setBgColor(0xff0055);
 Style unselectedStyle = new Style();
 unselectedStyle.setBgColor(0x004576);

 Table.setSelectedStyle(selectedStyle);
 table.setUnselectedStyle(unselectedStyle);
```

Its easy to figure out that this code applies to the table as a whole component, but I can't figure out how to make it apply to individual cells instead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

That's a selected style for the table not for the specific cell. You need to override the createCell method to do this manually or use the Resource Editor to define a selected style for the cell.